# Extract CSV column containing blank space to Bash array

Tags: bash, csv, array

I would like to export a CSV bookmarks file as

```
Physics,physics.stackexchange.com
Stack Overflow,stackoverflow.com
Unix & Linux,unix.stackexchange.com
```

into two Bash arrays. Each array would contain one column of the file. The first array would be

```
"Physics"   "Stack Overflow"   "Unix & Linux"
```

I have troubles to deals with the blank spaces. I tried to use `cut` like so

```bsh
declare names=($(cut -d ',' -f1 ~/bookmarks.csv))
```

which generates an array wherein all the words are separated. As an example, `echo ${names[1]}` returns

```bsh
Stack
```

and not

```
Stack Overflow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stack Overflow` has a space so it's being treated as two different variables when assigned to the array. In `BASH` and even other shells like `KSH`, etc, variable names cannot have spaces in them so a variable like `Stack Overflow` wouldn't work even if it were surrounded with single or double quotes.

You can see this with the following commands:

```
export Stack Overflow=name
echo $Stack Overflow
```

The output will be `Overflow` as the argument for `echo` is, in effect, $Stack, which hasn't been declared or assigned a value, and the word `Overflow`.

```
echo $Overflow
```

That will output `name` as the `export` command assigned that value to the variable `Stack` with `Overflow=name`.

If you try either of these:

```
export "Stack Overflow'=name
export 'Stack Overflow'=name
```

You'll get the error `-bash: export: Stack Overflow=name': not a valid identifier` or `-bash: export: Stack Overflow=name': not a valid identifier`.

One thing that you can do instead is to place underscores between the two strings:

```
export Stack_Overlow=name
```

That way, `echo $Stack_Overflow` will output `name`. That's going to require you to do more work because what you have in the CSV file contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Here the name of the array is names which does not contain any blank space. So I if understand well, each array element is in fact an independent variable. A solution would be to initialise an array with n elements (n being the number or rows) and to fill it up with the strings with a for loop?

Comment: @Loïc The value that's assigned to variable is `name`. The value of the variable can contain spaces but the name of the variable itself cannot contain spaces. You are correct in that each element in the array is an independent variable. With that being said, your proposed solution wouldn't work because it doesn't matter what method you use to assign variables to an array, you can't have variable names with spaces in them and that's why you are running into this issue.